# Double forward in one servlet

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets, forward

I have one JSP page that have a form.
When the button in this form is pushed, id called my MainServlet.
This is an example of my Servlet

```
/***** MainServlet *****/    

/* Call the servlet that comunicate with database */  
request.getRequestDispatcher("Servlet1").forward(request,response)

/* Return on the same JSP that have invoke MainServlet */
request.getRequestDispatcher("myJsp.jsp").forward(request,response);

return;
```

This is wrong because when I push the button in the form, my server return an error:
**"Cannot forward after response has been committed"**

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you get java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot forward to two different resources at the same time.

You need to again forward from `Servlet1` to `myJsp.jsp` using `request.getRequestDispatcher("myJsp.jsp").forward(request,response);`

You cannot just directly forward two times because when you do it once, your response is already committed and client will be served with the first resource.

You can use conditional statements which will forward to proper resource depending on the proper request.

Comment: I agree with you that I can't forward two times in one servlet. The problem is how to obtain the same ideal thing.

Comment: @electrixx90, as per your requirement, I've updated my answer. You need to forward to the jsp through servlet.

Comment: If you I use in MainServlet:
request.getRequestDispatcher("Servlet1").include(request, response);  request.getRequestDispatcher("myJsp.jsp").forward(request,response);
return;

But that don't func even if that can be right.

Comment: I mean, in Servlet1, use requestDispatcher to jsp

Comment: Ok the Servlet1 that I call with requestDispatcher in MainServlet must be mapped in the web.xml, is it right?

Comment: If you are using java EE 5 version, then yes, If you are using java EE 6 then your servlet needs to be annotated with `WebServlet` annotation.

Comment: Can you give me an example? Because all servlet that I mapped in web.xml are like this: 
<servlet>
    <description>
    </description>
    <display-name>...<display-name>
    <servlet-name>...<servlet-name>
    <servletclass>...</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>...</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>...</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

Comment: Ok that work for me but I don't know what is this "WebServlet annotation".
Thanks a lot.

Comment: @electrixx90 This will help you. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafu.html

Answer (score 0):

Once a request has been forward, the remaining codes are not executed. Its same like calling a return statement twice one after another in a method. 
If you want both forwards to work. You should use conditions, depending upon which, one of the  forward statement will be executed.