# How to do double forward in a single Servlet?

Tags: jsp, redirect, servlets, illegalstateexception, forward

I have created a web app using Servlet and JSP. My front page looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCF8t.png

I have two JSP files where I want to redirect my web app based on the click. If user click on delete, then my web app redirects it to FrontPage.jsp and when user click on create when web app should redirect it to index.jsp. I have referred this link [Double forward in one servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19156250/double-forward-in-one-servlet) and tried to use conditional statements which will forward to proper resource depending on the proper request. But when the user enters the collection name and click on create, I got an error which says:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed
```

This is my servlet:

```
     @WebServlet(description = "My first collection servlet", urlPatterns = {
    "/CollectionPath" })
public class Collection extends HttpServlet {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
      HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/html");

    String deleteFileName = request.getParameter("filename");
    System.out.println("you clicked on " + deleteFileName);
    File f = new File(
        "C:/Apps/eclipse-jee-mars-2-win32-x86_64/eclipse/" + deleteFileName);
    if (f.delete()) {
      System.out.println(f + "is deleted");

    } else {
      System.out.println(f + "is not deleteds");
    }


    String CollectionName = request.getParameter("myCollectionName");
    request.setAttribute("collectionName", CollectionName);

    if (CollectionName == null) {
      request.getRequestDispatcher("FrontPage.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

    else if (CollectionName != null) {
      request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

    String Pattern = request.getParameter("Pattern");
    String NotPattern = request.getParameter("NotPattern");
    String CollectionNameValue = request.getParameter("CollectionNameValue");
    File file = new File(CollectionNameValue + ".xml");
    file.createNewFile();
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
    System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
    writer.write("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><collection><includePatterns>"
        + Pattern + "</includePatterns><doNotIncludePatterns>" + NotPattern
        + "</doNotIncludePatterns></collection>");
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();

  }

}
```

I was able to redirect to the next page if user click on delete, but not able to redirect when user click on Create.
This is my FrontPage.jsp

```
<%@page import="java.io.File"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">

</head>

<body>

    A collection is a subset of the complete index. For example, create a
    marketing collection or an engineering collection to support searches
    only in the marketing or engineering pages in your index. You specify
    the contents of the collection using URL patterns. Create as many
    collections as you need.
    <br>
    <br>
    <b>Current Collections</b>

    <table width="100%" border="1">

        <%
          File folder = new File("C:/Apps/eclipse-jee-mars-2-win32-x86_64/eclipse");
          File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
          for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
        %>
        <tr>
            <%
              if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
            %>
            <td><%=listOfFiles[i].getName()%></td>
            <td>
                <form method="post" action='CollectionPath'>
                    <input type="submit" value="Delete"
                        onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to proceed?')">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<%=listOfFiles[i].getName()%>"
                        name="filename" />
                </form>
            </td>
            <%
              }
            %>
        </tr>
        <%
          }
        %>
    </table>
    <br>

    <title>Create New Collection</title>
    <h> <b>Create New Collection</b></h>
    <br> Collection Name:
    <textarea name="myCollectionName" cols="10" rows="1"></textarea>
    <br>
    <br>
    <form method="post" action='CollectionPath'>
        <input type="submit" value="Create"
            style="color: white; background: blue" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my index.jsp

```
<%@page import="java.io.File"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">

</head>

<body>

    A collection is a subset of the complete index. For example, create a
    marketing collection or an engineering collection to support searches
    only in the marketing or engineering pages in your index. You specify
    the contents of the collection using URL patterns. Create as many
    collections as you need.
    <br>
    <br>
    <b>Current Collections</b>

    <table width="100%" border="1">

        <%
          File folder = new File("C:/Apps/eclipse-jee-mars-2-win32-x86_64/eclipse");
          File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
          for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
        %>
        <tr>
            <%
              if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
            %>
            <td><%=listOfFiles[i].getName()%></td>
            <td>
                <form method="post" action='CollectionPath'>
                    <input type="submit" value="Delete"
                        onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to proceed?')">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<%=listOfFiles[i].getName()%>"
                        name="filename" />
                </form>
            </td>
            <%
              }
            %>
        </tr>
        <%
          }
        %>
    </table>
    <br>

    <title>Create New Collection</title>
    <h> <b>Create New Collection</b></h>
    <br> Collection Name:
    <textarea name="myCollectionName" cols="10" rows="1"></textarea>
    <br>
    <br>
    <form method="post" action='CollectionPath'>
        <input type="submit" value="Create"
            style="color: white; background: blue" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am newbie to Servlet and JSP. I might be missing something obvious. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You need to return; code execution doesn't stop just because you called a method.

Comment: forward, redirect can happen only once in servlet execution. You can have if else conditions to do forward, but cannot have multiple forwards executed in a servlet. I suggest you go through Headfirst servlets JSP book to get the basics of servlets clear

Comment: @DaveNewton I am confused. Can you please elaborate? What should I return?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the codes, you are writing something to your response after your forward.

Just stop doing it. or simply you can try adding a return after forward.

Or process result first and then forward in the end.

Comment: @NupurJaiswal Inshort, your forward should be the last line.